# Bootstrap-social-rails + OmniAuth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, omniauth

I want to use Bootstrap social buttons (Twitter) in my app created with OmniAuth.
My _link.html.erb:

```
<%- if devise_mapping.omniauthable? %>
  <%= link_to user_omniauth_authorize_path(:twitter), class: "btn btn-block    btn-social btn-twitter" do %>
     <span class="fa fa-twitter"></span> Sign in with Twitter
  <% end %>
<% end -%>
```

I have all needed gems and boostrap-social imported in my stylesheets. But button doesn't work - it looks just like wide, blue button, without Twitter logo.

Comment: Do you have the Font Awesome fonts and .css referenced in your project?

Comment: I installed awesome font gem, and in my css I have: 
@import "bootstrap-social"; (I also import boostrap sprockets obviously)

Comment: As Starscream said fontawesome seems not loaded in your project. Check browser console for error.

Comment: It sounds like the Font Awesome css isn't being referenced - can you find reference to it in your browser dev tools?

Comment: Do you have `@import "font-awesome-sprockets";` and 
`@import "font-awesome";` in your application.css ?

Comment: It started working locally, but after deploying to Heroku, I can't see Twitter icon again! What else can it be?